# Heating an electron gas

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics

Suppose you put some energy into an electron gas.As only electronic states very close to the Fermi energy can be heated, what happens to the excess energy? Is it just emitted as photons?

Edit: let me try to make it more clear using an example
If you shoot a laser beam at a metal, some of the energy is used to increase the electron temperature, but not all of the energy is transformed into heat. Neglecting the light reflected at the surface, what happens to the energy which does not contribute to heating the quasi-free electron gas? (The electronic heat capacity is not unity)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. If its, "What happens as one continually adds heat energy to a system that includes an electron when its in bound states--for example, an electron around an atom among many other atoms". (You need many other atoms in order to call it "heat", by definition. Otherwise you'd just use the more generic term "energy" if you were adding it to a single atom.) The answer to that is that the electron periodically jumps to higher states until it eventually leaves the highest bound state and becomes a free electron.

Comment: Ok, sorry for that. I've tried to make it more clear